# How to implement JSF navigation between two pages without using navigation-case in faces-config.xml

Tags: jsf, jsf-1.2

I am looking for a another way of `JSF` navigation other than mentioning navigation-cases in `faces-config.xml`.

At present i am using `faces-config.xml` to navigate. I want to clean it up.

Please suggest all other ways so that i can use whatever suits my need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For simple page-to-page navigation (without submitting anything) you should be using `<h:outputLink>` instead of `<h:commandLink>`.

So, **instead** of

```html
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="Page 1" action="page1" />
    <h:commandLink value="Page 2" action="page2" />
    <h:commandLink value="Page 3" action="page3" />
</h:form>
```

and those navigation cases

```xml
<navigation-rule>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>page1</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>page1.jsf</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>page2</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>page2.jsf</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>page3</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>page3.jsf</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

you *should* use

```html
<h:outputLink value="page1.jsf">Page 1</h:outputLink>
<h:outputLink value="page2.jsf">Page 2</h:outputLink>
<h:outputLink value="page3.jsf">Page 3</h:outputLink>
```

---

For real form submits you should rewrite the action methods to return `void` or `null` instead of an outcome. So, **instead** of

```html
<h:form>
     <h:inputText value="#{bean.query}" />
     <h:commandButton value="Search" action="#{bean.search}" />
</h:form>
```

with

```java
public String search() {
    results = searchService.find(query);
    return "results";
}
```

on one page and

```html
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.results}" var="result">
    ...
</h:dataTable>
```

on other page and this navigation case

```xml
<navigation-rule>
    <from-view-id>search.jsf</from-view-id>
    <navigation-case>
        <from-outcome>results</from-outcome>
        <to-view-id>results.jsf</to-view-id>
    </navigation-case>
</navigation-rule>
```

you *should* use

```html
<h:form rendered="#{empty bean.results}">
     <h:inputText value="#{bean.query}" />
     <h:commandButton value="Search" action="#{bean.search}" />
</h:form>
<h:dataTable value="#{bean.results}" var="result" rendered="#{not empty bean.results}">
    ...
</h:dataTable>
```

with

```java
public void search() {
    results = searchService.find(query);
}
```

You can if necessary include page fragments by `<jsp:include>`.

#### See also:

- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)

Answer (score 2):

### //JSF

```
<h:outputLink value="login.xhtml" >
    Login page
</h:outputLink>
```

### //HTML output

```
<a href="login.xhtml">
    Login page
</a>
```

Refer this URL for more info:-

**[commandLink and outputLink example](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/jsf-2-link-commandlink-and-outputlink-example/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can set the return value of a navigation action to the name of the page you want to go to (e.g. `return "page2";` to switch to *page2.jsf*). But as far as I know, this feature has been implemented first in JSF 2.0.

Comment: Thanks for the response.Can you suggest any method for JSF 1.X because i am using JSF 1.2?

Comment: Hi any idea how to archieve this in JSF 1.2 ?

Comment: No, as far as I know, this is a feature that came with 2.0 first. I think you will have to have a config file with `navigation-case`s, so that JSF knows which `commandAction` return value leads to which page.